# Restricting a user to a specific PC is affecting OWA

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

When I restrict a user to logon to a specific PC (using the user account setting in AD - Account > log on to) it's affecting Outlook Web Access when the user tries to access his/her mailbox remotely and from their mobile devices. If I set it to log on to "All Computers" everything works well. Is there  a work-around for this?

I am running Windows Server 2003 SP2 for AD and Exchange Server 2003.

Answer (score 4):

Add the OWA server itself to the user's "Log On To" list and see how things work. It's surprising me a bit that the restriction would apply in the case of a non-interactive logon but it's worth a shot.

Comment: This is correct. The user needs the Exchange server added to the list of computers they are allowed to log on to in order for them to use OWA.